# Remove all single characters from string using xslt1.0

Tags: xslt-1.0

```
<title>
 <article_title>Land a b   c   d      Band</article_title>
</title>
```

using the following function

```
replace(article_title, '(^[^ ]+)(.+\s+)([^ ]+)$', '$1 $3')
```

this string in  is transformed to  Land Band  which is exactly what i want.

but the problem is i need this solution in xslt 1.0  since the java app that i am working with can only handle xslt 1.0 parsing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This XSLT 1.0 transformation** (there is a nasty SO bug and the code isn't indented -- I apologize for this visual mess...):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="text()" name="removeSingles">
   <xsl:param name="pText" select="."/>

   <xsl:variable name="vText" select="normalize-space($pText)"/>

   <xsl:if test="string-length($vText)">
    <xsl:variable name="vLeftChars" select=
    "substring-before(concat($vText, ' '), ' ')"/>

    <xsl:if test="string-length($vLeftChars) >1">
     <xsl:value-of select="$vLeftChars"/>
     <xsl:if test=
      "not(string-length($vLeftChars)
          >=
           string-length($vText)
           )
      ">
       <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:if>

    <xsl:call-template name="removeSingles">
     <xsl:with-param name="pText" select=
     "substring-after($vText, ' ')"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
   </xsl:if>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<title>
 <article_title>Land a b   c   d      Band</article_title>
</title>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<title>
   <article_title>Land Band</article_title>
</title>
```

Comment: Dimitre, thanks looks like it should work, how do i call this ? is this correct <xsl:value-of select="removeSingles"/>

Comment: @sanjay: What do you mean by "Its not working". I always test my answers before publishing them. Just run the transformation on the provided XML document and you should get the reported result. If not, then either you modified the XSLT code, or you modified the XML file, or both, or your XSLT processor is buggy / not fully compliant.

Comment: Dimitre, I really appreciate your effort and time, I have to apply this only to a particular element on my xml. This is how i am calling <xsl:value-of select="removeSingles"/> is this correct ?

Comment: @sanjay: No, you need to: `<xsl:call-template name="removeSingles"> <xsl:with-param name="pText" select="yourElement"/></xsl:call-template>` . Also, remove the `match="text()"` from the `removeSingles` `xsl:template` instruction.

Comment: Dimitri, Thank you very much.....it working. In your previous comment u asked me to remove match="text()" How do i do that and what will be the benefit ?

Comment: @sanjay: You just replace ` <xsl:template match="text()" name="removeSingles">` with ` <xsl:template name="removeSingles">` THe former matches *every text node* but you want to process in this way only certain nodes, not every one of them.

Comment: Dimitre, i just have to add one more requirement.

Comment: Dimitre, i just have to add one more requirement. if there is a wildcard in the string then the word containing the wildcard has to be at least three char in length, suppose if the string is 'Land aa* Band' then the output has to be 'Land band'  if the string is 'Land aaa* Band' then it is ok, if the string is 'Land aa*aaaa Band' then the result should be 'Land Band' so we have to count chars before * in the word if the length is less than 3 then remove the word.